# How to get and set input value with xsl + php?

Tags: php, xslt

I have in xsl code:

```
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
```

But in php

```
$value =  $_POST['subject'];
```

and

```
$("#subject").val(new_value);
```

does not work.

Comment: Because `#subject` is selector by `id` and not by `name`.

Comment: You need to set an id in your input-tag

Comment: And set POST method on your form type

Comment: I've changed to <input type="text" id="subject" /> and still not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'subject'  as `id` in input box.

Like below-

```js
$("#subject").val('new_value');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
```

Comment: I've changed to <input type="text" id="subject" /> and still not work.

Comment: Can you show full script where `$("#subject").val(new_value);` is used ?